# What's the meaning of !int_variable--?

Tags: c, if-statement, logical-operators, negation

I can't understand what the following code is doing on `s`:

```
 if(!s--)
```

`s` is an `int`

Comment: 1) that's not a function. 2) use divide and conquer. there are only three things there: `if`. `!` and `--`.

Comment: At first, compiler is checking if s is equal to zero to enter into the if block. Then s is decremented by 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`!` is called `negation` operator. It is a logical operator.

See the [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation) here.

```
if(!s--)
```

The order in which it executes

1. check the value of `s` is `0` or not , if `s` is `0`, `if` condition is success [thanks to the `!` operator], otherwise, failure.
2. After that, decrement `s` by one unit.
3. Based on the evaluation of `if` condition, continue the execution [code under `if` condition, or next block of code].

Answer (score 3):

Actually, it's misleading.

You are testing is `s` is different from 0 (with `if (!s)`). And then, afterward, whatever the result is, you're decreasing it.

So, it's two different operations.
It could be written this way :

```
if (!s)
{
     s--;
     //...
}
else
{
     s--;
}
```